# behat, gherkin and regex: using "not" or not

Tags: regex, behat, gherkin

I have behat conditions which I want to cover with on function, using "not":
`Given this is happening` and `Given this is NOT happening`. I can't find a regular expression that works though.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
/**
 * @Given /^this is<regexCheckingNOT> happening$/
 */
public function thisIsHappening($not)
{
    if ($not) {
        // do this
    }

    // do that anyway
}
```

I tried these without success:

- `@Given /^this is(? NOT| ) happening$/`
- `@Given /^this is( )?(NOT)? happening$/`

and I cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: Try this: `^this is (NOT)? happening$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW4qE3/1)

Comment: @Druzion the regex works but then how can I know, inside of the function, if "NOT" was specified? When use your regex and `$not` as the argument I get `Can not find a matching value for an argument '$not'`

Comment: I do not know anything about Behat or Gherkin, but in plain PHP you can use 'preg_match()' to find matches. It returns an array and you can see if the first match, `[1]` contains `"NOT"`

Comment: @Druzion Ok, thank you for the help

Comment: Why the downvote on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by making " not" optional:

```php
/**
 * @Given /^this is( not)? happening$/
 */
public function thisIsHappening($not = null)
{
    if (null !== $not) {
        // do this
    }

    // do that anyway
}
```

You'll need to provide a default value (i.e. `null`) as this argument will not be present for the "this is happening" step.

However, I'd consider making this two separate methods to make them simpler:

```php
/**
 * @Given this is happening
 */
public function thisIsHappening()
{
    // do that anyway
}

/**
 * @Given this is not happening
 */
public function thisIsNotHappening()
{
    // do this

    // do that anyway if you need something to happen in both cases
    $this->thisIsHappening();
}
```

Comment: @Druzion Jakub provided the way to check if NOT was captured by the regex in Behat, that's not copying your comment

Comment: To be clear you're creating an optional capturing group (regex thingie). Is this documented somewhere in behat docs? Or is it just assumed from usage of regex?

Answer (score 1):

To further the accepted answer, you could also use something like this:

```
/**
 * @Given /^this is(| not)? happening$/
 */
public function thisIsHappening($not)
{
    if ($not === " not") {
        // do this
    } else {
    // do that anyway
    }
}
```

It follows the same rules as the accepted, but also means you do not have to set a default value for `$not`, as it could be " not" or blank.

Comment: I see your point, so by default the `$not === ""` but isn't then the "?" redundant? There will always be an "empty string", so `is(| not)` should be enough. But I find this less readable than `( not)?` to be honest.

Comment: @jave.web its the readability for me - the capture group is greedy but the naked eye will like the ? better - its redundancy for communications sake for sure